Launching Visual Studio 2022 Community edition... how?
I've just installed VS-CE under Windows, after the install it started up, I even managed to build and run a simple GUI project. I shut the IDE down, but when I tried to start it up later there was no shortcut on the desktop. Where is the startup file so I can create a desktop shortcut? Trying to find something by just trolling the folders will take an eternity.

In the windows start menu? It even has a search field ...

Even better, you don't even have to click in the search area. Just click the Start Menu (or hit the Windows key on the keyboard) and then immediately start typing "Visual Studio ..." and you'll get a hit (hopefully!).

The path for VS IDE is here:
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.
You can right-click the devenv.exe and use send-to desktop(create a shortcut) to create a shortcut on desktop.
